# Where is svn.exe in my machine?

Tags: svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I have **Tortoise svn** installed on my desktop. I want to perform some tasks using **commandline** svn.exe? But I am not able to find **svn.exe** on my machine.

Do we have to install something else to get the **svn.exe** commands?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The subversion program code is linked into the TortoiseSVN binary.  You can install a compatible discrete version if you need to access the repository from the command line.

UPDATE:  Recent versions of the TortoiseSVN package can install a discrete svn.exe in addition to the one linked into the GUI binary.  It is located in the same bin directory where the main program is installed.
In the installer, the command line tools need to be selected for this:
[image]

(If you have already installed TortoiseSVN, then rerun the installer and select "Modify")
[image: Modify installation]

Comment: What is a  compatible discrete version?

Comment: TortoiseSVN installer has two version numbers.  The first one is the version of the GUI shell itself.  The second is the version of subversion linked into it.  If you will install a discrete version, you want one the same or close to the linked-in version.  You can also find the svn version number with the context menu about box.

Comment: So If I update the TSVN GUI I need to update the SVN client as well?

Comment: @Amitabh if you update TSVN you may need to update SVN to the same major release version. i.e. TSVN 1.6.8 SVN 1.6.6 will be compatible

Comment: Take a look a Stefan Egli answer.  V1.7 comes with the option to also install the svn binaries.

Comment: If you have already installed TortoiseSVN 1.7, then try to reinstall it, and it will give you the option to Modify the install. Click the X'ed out command line option and choose to also install that. Worked for me

Comment: I have tried by modifying the installer and gave command line tools for installation. I couldn't find "svn.exe".

Comment: This answer shows how to install TortoiseSVN and the svn command-line client using msiexec: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40281053/755405

Comment: when I chose this option it asks me to insert a disk. o_O

Answer (score 46):

TortoiseSVN 1.7 has an option for installing the command line tools.

It isn't checked by default, but you can run the installer again and select it. It will also automatically update your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 23):

During the installation of TortoiseSVN, check the *Command Line Client Tools*. This will create the file `svn.exe` inside the folder `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`.

Answer (score 16):

TortoiseSVN doesn't use svn.exe  it has SVN library compiled in.   If you need to run your own tasks you would have to install stand alone subversion client.  You either from Cygwin [http://cygwin.com ] or get a native version from http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

Comment: I've downloaded VisualSVN (client version), and the setup package includes the Command Line. thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to use SVN.EXE, there are several companies that compile official binaries that are available for free download.  For example, Collabnet:

http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Silk installation, try:

> "\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin"

Comment: cinst sliksvn (http://chocolatey.org/packages/sliksvn), simple way to install it and adds it to your path.

Answer (score 4):

Yes reinstall and select command line to get the svn in Program Files-> Tortoise SVN folder.

Comment: It looks to me as if you were describing the solution to a different problem, not to the one asked by the OP. Can you please check you are answering the question?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you need to do, [automating TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) may be a good solution.  For example, the following will update a repository and close the TortoiseSVN window if there were no errors or conflicts:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\path\to\repo\" /closeonend:2
```

Comment: The thing is, you cannot hide the dialog box on commit

Answer (score 2):

Download it from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

and run the setup program. The executables are in:

\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin

for the default installation.

Comment: nice addition to more common GUI tools like TortoiseSVN

Comment: downvoted because these binary package does not receive updates anymore

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of the TortoiseSVN package can install a discrete svn.exe in addition to the one linked into the GUI binary. It is located in the same bin directory where the main program is installed. (If you have already installed TortoiseSVN, then **rerun the installer**, select Modify, and **select command line tools for installation**.)

Answer (score 2):

I installed `TortoiseSVN-1.12.2.28653-x64-svn-1.12.2` in Windows 10 with commandline tool enabled. Still it didn't have the `svn.exe` file inside the `bin` folder.

So I downloaded Apache Subversion commandline tools from https://www.visualsvn.com/files/Apache-Subversion-1.13.0.zip. After unzipping, I have put the following two locations into my PATH variable:

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
E:\Apache-Subversion-1.13.0\bin
```

Everything works fine for me after this configuration.I wanted to use SVN in VsCode IDE.

Answer (score 2):

If Subversion is already installed ,there's no need to reinstall it with the command line client tools.
Simply Goto

```
Start(Rightclick) ->App and Feature ->TortoiseSvn->Modify->Install command line client tools.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can find the svn.exe on this location:

> C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

If you have already installed TortoiseSVN and still can't find the file the `svn.exe` on the given location, then you need to rerun the TortoiseSVN installer, click on 'Modify' and select Command Line Tools and after installation is successfully finished, you can now find the 'svn.exe' on given location on your drive.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if subversion installed on your machine? if not look at what server your tortoisesvn is setup to connect to.

the default location when subversion is installed is c:\program files\subversion
you can find svn.exe in c:\program files\subversion\bin where you can run your cmd line actions.

Answer (score -1):

```
def proc = 'cmd /c C:/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:/work/new/1.2/" /closeonend:2'.execute()
```

This is my 'svn.groovy' file.