# Subversion: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'

Tags: svn

When I issue the below from the **command line:**

> svn add
>   SomeFileInMyWorkingDirectory.zip

I get:

> svn: This client is too old to work
>   working copy '.'; Please get a newer
>   subversion client.

OK, this is pretty straight-forward. But what has me confused is that
when I issue the following command:

> svn --version

The response I get is

```
svn, version 1.4.3 (r23084)
```

But, when I go to the ToirtiseSVN client and click on "about" I get:

> TortoiseSVN 1.6.8, Build 19260 - 32
>   Bit , 2010/04/16 20:20:11 Subversion
>   1.6.11,  apr 1.3.8 apr-utils 1.3.9 neon 0.29.3 OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
>   zlib 1.2.3

It seems that my command line version is older than the GUI but they both 
came from the same download.

Why are the GUI and the command line tools two different versions? How do I update the command-line only? Can somebody point me to a link where I can get these files? 
I am using Windows XP, C#, ASP.NET 3.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseSVN does not install a command line version of svn.  See this previous SOF question for details:

[Where is svn.exe in my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967176/where-is-svn-exe-in-my-machine/2967196#2967196)

You should locate and remove the existing stand alone 1.4.3 version then install a current one.  They can be obtained from:

http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

Comment: As a note: newer TortoiseSVN *can* install matching command line tools.