# Commit through Phing using eclipse on Windows

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, phing

I am using eclipse to commit my changes to SVN.
Now I want to automate few things using Phing, which would do commit with the build process.

Phing code for svn commit is:

```
<svncommit svnpath="/usr/bin/svn" workingcopy="path/to/my/working/copy" recursive="true" message="my commit message"/>
```

Above works well on my Linux (ubuntu) machine.

At work, I have to use a Windows box :( and I am not sure what I should be using in svnpath.

Do I need to install any other software?  I am not sure if I can use the path of the subversion plugin for eclipse! I don't even know its path.

Can any one please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

SVN (Subversion) Windows builds can be found here: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

> but it does not add any new folder/files that I have created!

i am not familiar with phing on eclipse, but it seems you are missing **-all** option (add all)

> ```
> -a , --all
>       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new
>       files you have not told git about are not affected.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried to svncommit in phing on windows, but my guess is to download+install [tortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and use the `svn.exe` in `svnpath`.

I've used svnexport in phing on Windows before, and that worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to install tortoiseSVN and let you know in few mins if that works for me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I was not able to find svn.exe of tortoiseSVN, but I used this C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe, but seems not doing any thing! would it be possible to tell me the path for svn?

Comment: Guess I was using a custom package. This thread has a description for `svn.exe`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967176/where-is-svn-exe-in-my-machine

Answer (score 0):

Ok Tortoise svn did not work for me!
But subversion for windows worked for me partially!!!! http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/

Calling this file from Phing, does commit my changes, but it does not add any new folder/files that I have created! So though I have answered my own quetion, but still the answer is partial!!!

Please let me know if someone has got all of the things working.
My goal - Work with Phing in Eclipse on WINDOWS to auto commit my changes including any new files/folders.

----------------------------Update--------------------

Alright got a way around for this. And I got my answer from the following question.

[How do I 'svn add' all unversioned files to SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071857/how-do-i-svn-add-all-unversioned-files-to-svn)

Thanks,
Tanmay