# Where is svn.exe for TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is svn.exe in my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967176/where-is-svn-exe-in-my-machine)

I try change username for my repository with command

```
svn propset --revprop svn:author
```

I cannot find program **svn.exe**. What is wrong

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Current versions of TortoiseSVN do not install command-line SVN client by default. You'll have to:

- Select it explicitly in the installer (see comment by Stefan)
- Download it and install it separately from http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html.

Comment: TSVN 1.7 has the SVN command line client tools included, but you must explicitly select them during installation.

Comment: This answer shows how to install TortoiseSVN and the svn command-line client using msiexec: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40281053/755405

Comment: You can re-download the installer, and choose "modify" to select the command line tools to be installed.

Answer (score 8):

1. You can set properties over GUI
2. You can make full install of TSVN 1.7.*, which have command-line svn-programs