# How can I install TortoiseSVN with commands using command line msiexec.exe?

Tags: tortoisesvn, windows-installer

I need to create a command line that will install TortoiseSVN and include the Subversion command line utilities.

What options on the msiexec.exe command line would tell the installer to include the command set?

TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3.msi

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 6):

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/j1e_6v2IfPQ

```
msiexec.exe /i TortoiseSVN-1.9.3.27038-x64-svn-1.9.3.msi /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL
```