# "Use command line client" option is not available in Android Studio 3.2.1 for subversion

Tags: android, android-studio, svn, svn-checkout

I have implemented an android project and want to integrate subversion into Android Studio but in setting of subversion I'm not getting the option of "Use command line client" and getting this below error :

**Can't use Subversion command line client: svn The path to the Subversion executable is probably wrong**

[image]

Is there any solution to solve these issue? Please help me out How do I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed SVN. Note that [a pure TortoiseSVN doesn't have SVN command line installed by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7912196/9035237). Then

- Add the directory which can be used to find `svn` executable into environment variable `PATH`

or

- Specify the absolute path of `svn` executable in your Android Studio settings.

Comment: Tortoise SVN is installed. Environment variable is already set. But the option for unchecking command line is not found in the latest Android Studio. I hope the command line execution of svn is not installed. Is there any work around for this ?