# "svn is not recognized" error in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, svn, gource

I'm trying to reach SVN from Windows PowerShell but I can't. For example, if I type `svn help` I get:

> svn : The term 'svn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have TortoiseSVN installed on the computer which should to my knowledge should allow me to use `svn` commands.

I also have the same problem when I try to use Gource.

Comment: Can you give us the content of `echo %PATH%`, executed from command line?

Comment: What @vitozev said. The location of `svn`  is not in any of the locations defined by the environment variable path. Check `$env:Path` in PowerShell

Comment: `TortoiseSVN` has an option for installing the command line tools. It isn't checked by default, but you can run the installer again and select it. It will also automatically update your `PATH` environment variable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9874961/1023562 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7769846/1023562

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (where it wouldn't run in PowerShell).  I had to enter the full path for SVN (e.g. "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe").  That worked for me.

**Edit:** I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578871/passing-parameters-to-svn-in-a-powershell-script), and got this as part of the answer.  Put it into an alias:

```
set-alias svn "c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe"
```

Hope that helps!