# Passing parameters to SVN in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, svn, scripting

I am trying to automate a procedure that uses SVN, and I am trying to teach myself PowerShell (and scripting) in the process.

I set up a PowerShell script that reads values for revision numbers and my folder path, like this:

```
$GetSVN = read-host "Enter the SVN folder path: "
$RevStart = read-host "Enter the starting revision: "
$RevEnd   = read-host "Enter the ending revision: "
```

It then calls SVN and (tries to) pass the parameters.

**Here's my problem:** When I try to call SVN as follows:

```
& "c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" "-log -r $RevStart`:$RevEnd  $GetSVN"
```

I get the following message:

```
svn: E205000: Non-numeric limit argument given
svn: E200004: Could not convert 'og -r BASE:#### [SVN file path]' into a number
```

Okay, fine.  I tried adding an extra space before "-log".  But when I do that, here's what happens:

```
Unknown subcommand: ' -log -r BASE:#### [SVN file path]'
```

Huh?!?  What's going on with this?  I've tried various variations of this, all to no avail.  I can't find an answer to this anywhere.  Does anyone have any insight?

I am a newbie to PowerShell scripting, so feel free to answer as such.

Thanks in advance . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call is wrong, multiple parameters are grouped as one. Better and correct way to do it is this:

```
set-alias svn "c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" 
svn log -r $RevStart`:$RevEnd $GetSVN
```

Setting alias is cosmetics. The real problem were `"` placement.

Comment: Never mind, got it!  It *did* work, but the problem was that I was putting the "-" before "log" (I forgot that this was invalid syntax).