# How to svn commit with no dialog box

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Hi I have TortoiseSVN installed and I need to create a bat file to commit. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252872/how-do-i-not-display-the-dialog-on-svn-tortoise-commit) but when I try it I get an error that svn is an un-recognised command. How do I get around this.

Comment: Answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967176/where-is-svn-exe-in-my-machine

Comment: The question you linked to has the answer you need. You must use svn.exe. You "get around this" by installing svn.exe. It's included in the installation of TortoiseSVN 1.7 and newer - so if you have that, you just need to update $PATH% to include the path where it's located, or specify the full path to the EXE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer avri gave me I downloaded [this](http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/win32svn/1.7.8/apache22/Setup-Subversion-1.7.8.msi) and installed it on my ci server.