# Need return code for automatic update script

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have written an automatic update script for SVN (tortoiseSVN) like this : 
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"my_path" /closeonend:0. After the update is completed, I will start my weblogic. But I need a way to find whether the svn update has resulted in any conflicts so that I will not start weblogic in that case. Is there any way or any return codes that I can check that will help me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[TortoiseSVN documentation about automation](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html):

> **Important** Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Subversion command line client instead.

See also this similar question: [How do I not display the dialog on SVN Tortoise Commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252872/how-do-i-not-display-the-dialog-on-svn-tortoise-commit)

So use the svn command line client. But be aware, that the command line client also has no really specific exit codes:

> The "svn" command-line tool doesn't return much specific info in the exit code, just "0 == worked" / "1 == failed".
>
> The information is in the messages printed out prior to failure. An extensive, but not exhaustive, list of the key strings in those messages may be found at:
>
> [http://svn.apache.or​g/repos/asf/subversi​on/trunk/subversion/​include/svn_error_co​des.h](http://%20http://svn.apache.or%E2%80%8Bg/repos/asf/subversi%E2%80%8Bon/trunk/subversion/%E2%80%8Binclude/svn_error_co%E2%80%8Bdes.h)
>
> (*from https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=375149)*